# Derive type of method's callback argument from constructor option's return type

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a [Webhooks SDK](https://github.com/octokit/webhooks.js). A minimal code example looks like this

```
const webhooks = new Webhooks({
  secret: "secret",
  path: "/webhooks"
});
webhooks.on("issues", (event) => {
  console.log(event.name); // event type is set to { name: string, payload: any }
});
```

The `Webhooks` constructor supports a `transform` option which can mutate the `event` object before it is passed to the event handlers:

```
const webhooks = new Webhooks({
  secret: "bleh",
  path: "/webhooks",
  transform: (event) => Object.assign(event, { foo: "bar" })
});
webhooks.on("issues", (event) => {
  console.log(event.foo); // event type should be { name: string, payload: any, foo: string }
});
```

My question is: how can I derive the `event` type in the `webhooks.on()` callback based on the `transform` constructor option?

I have a minimal test case on the [TypeScript playground](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=1&pln=8&pc=1#code/PTAEHEHsEMBsGcBcAoEoCMA6UBJAZqJAA4AuAlpAHbyYkBO01ekdAtqGfKJZCaPAFMSAGlAkAFgMr8hYyaAEA3KXxIBPIgI7SJWzFQAUASlABjOLABG0UwGsxkOVoEAPTuUoBzUAHUBl8UhIWwBRZUpVDQFUMAAmbHxCUgpqWgYmFnZOGREnaUFVeSUVMSjtJ1B9SmMzC2s7BwrdUDohAFc6SmBW%20EhYZVLNQgJicioaekZ4ZjZkZHUhvwCg0PCSAB4AFVAAXlBGNQA%20XdAAb2RQS%205oVgFEUAByeHoyLwfhC6uiaDVYGAATe6bZAAXzmCy0YRUAGE6jZ7HsDMUIvcloFglCIiYdsdFJAyP95mVNulppkALJCQL-E5bBQuEhSf5cNErTEkQ5Itao-zo1YqbHHbYAH1AAAU6JBWJwBAAZMi2ARbQ5EoYAeWS4xO5yuYlJM1YAH4gfqKVTIISwchTLBoPAWbyVlwdV82pZYGRTIRqsiSPdnnRXp5RL6ABKMf6wAR0e7s2GwKzwkwu3WXNCYDOfS5W3Wmcb0NqmEgsAyjFLwY2gDVjajJrOp9OZ3Vgq156h8ADujuC8HQJ0oAg7vm7tngxmQXeWPawhgezEg7wUa12xxTZnGfQEmD%20ni5KkwlBuAiMoJP1vzoEnfPgsX7g%20HU9HBjXkwybD3WLO9d1rRIHWkaqWAAVgIRaYHa8BkJ4PprKIpygPO9wPNYdAPCCJ7NqeE4jjeVQGHOQSLr6K5frqaCbGqAAiar3Kw0CKnI2Qdiwtj1m2vRRtukC7r6mDzie6FAA), and a failing test in a [pull request on the repository](https://github.com/octokit/webhooks.js/pull/177)

Answer (score 1):

Does something like this work for you?

```
type WebhookEvent<T = any> = {
    name: 'string',
    payload: T
}

type TransformMethod<T extends any> = (event: WebhookEvent) => WebhookEvent<T>
// here the change using ReturnType
type EventCallback<T extends WebhookEvent> = (event: ReturnType<TransformMethod<T>>) => void
type Options<T extends WebhookEvent> = {
    transform?: TransformMethod<T>
}

class Webhooks<T extends any> {
    public on(event: string, eventHandler: EventCallback<T>) {
        // ...
    }

    constructor(options?: Options<T>) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The key point is configuring `event` to be of the type of the `ReturnType<TransformMethod>` and adding some generics here and there

notes:

- if you use `Object.assign`, the typings on the return of the `transform` function will be relaxed - it won't check that the object
- if you return a PromiseLike, the event will return an object or a Promise like object, so you will have to wait for the promise in the `on`. For now, I Remove the promise part so its easier, but you can add it if you adapt this

[here is the playground](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?#code/PTAEHEHsEMBsGcBcAoEoCMA6UBJAZqJAA4AuAlpAHbyYkBO01ekdAtqGfKJZCaPAFMSAGlAkAFgMr8hYyaAEA3KXxIBPIgI7SJWzFQAUASlABjOLABG0UwGsxkOVoEAPTuUoBzUAHUBl8UhIWwBRZUpVDQFUMAAmbHxCUgpqWgYmFnZOGREnaUFVeSUVMSjtJ1B9SmMzC2s7BwrdUDohAFc6SmBW+EhYZVLNQgJicioaekZ4ZjZkZHUhvwCg0PCSAB4AFVAAXlBGNQA+XdAAb2RQS+5oVgFEUAByeHoyLwfhC6uiaDVYGAATe6bZAAXzmCy0m3S00yAFkhIF-lsFC4SFJ-lwDsc9gZihF7ktAsEwioTDtjoSViSIltDvMytSSABhOo2WzI1xoygY-aUI4nXFre4AJXanU2US20JmrHhEkgSM2h0OZOOikgZH+9KGAHlkuMOaj0Zi+dizp9LpMMmwAPxA6VwhEK2mguamWDQeBcSnBeCGrk8rHmq6gIhtSywMimQjVPEke7POivTyiOMACUY-1gAjo90ZLNgVjZtJM5xDIbQmCrFtAYJrpnG9DaphILAMoxS8DtoD1Y2oJeD5culerIbBdYb1D4AHd-ETbPB0CdKAJp745yt4MZkLPlr6sIYHsxIO8FGtdscy1dJ71s5g-p5BSpMJQbgIjKCP8gbzON77Ysuq7rnuC7rKcoDHgmLxeKI1gAF73JQbSsJYOa1ocBhXpaDpsE+ESljWIatCQHTSFhQ5XK+tz3HGL5vh8FHlt8vwAvc4GQY8x6nvB9wAWCjH8Vc44fru87wPEh5cam57koOly0cxfzQP8mDHjWaCbDqAAiOr3Kw0C2FoEjZNOLC2PW4x9AI96QI+Ck-EpKnHh+Ib2SxymYPBn5AA)

Then you can do

```
const webhooks2 = new Webhooks<{ foo: string }>({
    transform(event) {
        return Object.assign(event, { foo: 'bar'})
    }
})
webhooks2.on('foo', event => {
    event.payload.foo
    // here autocomplete works
    console.log(event.payload.foo)
})
```

Comment: That would be a potential workaround, but I want to see if it's possible to make it work without the type argument

Comment: if you drop the `<{ foo: string }>` when doing `new Webhooks` TS will still infer the returned type from `transform`

Comment: One minor note: I didn't want to only extend the `event.payload` property, but the entire `event` object. Here is another approach that addresses that correctly, and also works with the `PromiseLike`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63236547/206879

Comment: oh I see, I thought you wanted to extend payload because of the generics. I got confused by the request

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution provided by [Andrew Branch](https://github.com/andrewbranch) from the TypeScript team:

```
type WebhookEvent<T = any> = {
    name: 'string',
    payload: T
}

type TransformMethod<T extends WebhookEvent> = (event: WebhookEvent) => T | PromiseLike<T>
type Options<T extends WebhookEvent> = {
    transform?: TransformMethod<T>
}

class Webhooks<T extends WebhookEvent> {
    public on(event: string, eventHandler: (event: T) => void) {
        // ...
    }

    constructor(options?: Options<T>) {
        // ...
    }
}

const webhooks1 = new Webhooks()
webhooks1.on('foo', event => {
    console.log(event.name)
})

const webhooks2 = new Webhooks({
    transform(event) {
        return Object.assign(event, { foo: 'bar'})
    }
})
webhooks2.on('foo', event => {
    console.log(event.foo)
})
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?#code/PTAEHEHsEMBsGcBcAoEoCMA6UBJAZqJAA4AuAlpAHbyYkBO01ekdAtqGfKJZCaPAFMSAGlAkAFgMr8hYyaAEA3KXxIBPIgI7SJWzFQAUASlABjOLABG0UwGsxkOVoEAPTuUoBzUAHUBl8UhIWwBRZUpVDQFUMAAmbHxCUgpqWgYmFnZOGREnaUFVeSUVMSjtJ1B9SmMzC2s7BwrdUDohAFc6SmBW%20EhYZVLNQgJicioaekZ4ZjZkZHUhvwCg0PCSAB4AFVAAXlBGNQA%20XdAAb2RQS%205oVgFEUAByeHoyLwfhC6uiaDVYGAATe6bZAAXzmCy0m3S00yAFkhIF-lsFC4SFJ-lwloFgmEVMc9gZihF7liVriIiYdsdtgAfUAABTokFYnAEABkyLYBFtDvMygB5ZLjZGuNGUDG%20fzY1Z4k7nK5iaEzVgAfiBSrhCMgSM2vLByFMsGg8ExUpW8BFqPRpuWOLWx3lXzallgZFMhGqRJI92edFenlEXoAEox-rABHR7oS1kDKcdFJAyP8TI6FZc0JhM59LvqFaZxvQ2qYSCwDKMUvA1aBBWNqDyU9m0xmswqwfr89Q%20AB3M3BeDoE6UARdyW22zwYzIHtj-tVAwPZiQd4KNa7B2Nju9cOYP6eaMqTCUG4CIyg08GgugafS%20CxQfD0c3gypxVTZX7ilnRsK1okDrSflLAAKwEYtMGNeAyE8T01lEU5QEXe4HmsOgHhBU9WzPKde3HeJDAXIJly9NcvwVNBNn5AARfl7lYaAuTkbIuxYWwN3GPoBB3SA9y9TBF1PdCgA)